# URL connection from adls Gen2 from Power BI Advanced Editor

Tags: powerbi, azure-functions, powerbi-desktop, azure-data-lake-gen2

I can pull data from adls gen1 into Power BI Desktop using this code in advanced editor (m query).

```
“Adl:// url “ meta [ isparameterquery =true, type=any, isparameterqueryrequired=true]
```

How do I pull data from Gen2 using similar code?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect Azure data lake gen2 in Power BI desktop, please refer to the following steps

1. [Create Azure data lake gen2 storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-create?tabs=azure-portal)
2. You are granted one of the following roles for the storage account: **Blob Data Reader**, **Blob Data Contributor**, or **Blob Data Owner**. Regarding how to grant permissions, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad).
3. Connect

   a. From the **Home** tab of the Ribbon, select **Get Data**, and then select **More**.

   b. select **Azure > Azure Data Lake Store Gen2**, and then select **Connect**
   [image]

   c. In the **Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2** dialog box, you can provide the URL to your Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 account, filesystem, or subfolder using the container endpoint format, such as `https://<accountname>.dfs.core.windows.net/<filesystemname>/<subfolder>`
   [image]

   d. If this is the first time you're using this URL address, you'll be asked to select the authentication method: **Organizational account method** and **Account key method**
   [image]

   f. Query

For more details, please refer to the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/datalakestorage)